# How to say "You are able to" or "You can do this"

Tags: grammar, phrase-requests, english-to-japanese, modality, permission

Title says it all. I am looking for sentence structures that can convey this meaning.

Comment: "You can do this" in the sense of giving permission?

Comment: @chocolate Yes I meant by giving permission

Comment: How is this not a duplicate of another question?

Answer (score 2):

To say "you can/may ____" or "it's okay to ____", use this structure:

> [verb, te-form] + も (optional) + いい

This can also be used with negatives to say "it's okay not to ____"

**Positive Example: 「入っていいですよ」** (inviting someone to come into your house/room)

**Positive Example (casual): 「入っていいよ」**

**Negative Example: 「心配しなくていいですよ」** "It's okay"/"Don't worry (about it)"; literally "it's okay not to worry"

**Negative Example (casual): 「心配しなくていいよ」**

Notes:

- も, like a lot of other particles, is usually *ommitted* when spoken or in chat and *included* in formal, written communication like e-mail, letters, papers, books, etc.
- The sentence ending ~よ is often tagged on the end of sentences that use this structure.

Answer (score 0):

It differs depending on the connotation you want to attach to 'able to'

1. Ability : できる or the 可能形 (ability form of verbs)
   For example, 自分で料理できますか？means are you able to do the cooking yourself? 
   ピアノが弾けます (possibility form of 弾く) means I am able to play the piano.
2. Permission : でもいい？ or 〜っていいよ
   ちょっとトイレに行ってもいい？
   Means can I go to the toilet for a bit? This indicates not the ability to go to the toilet but rather the permission to go to the toilet.
3. Possibility : 可能
   Literally the word means possibility, and this refers more to things which are physically possible, or possible within a set of rules.  Also is a more formal form of no.1.
   For example, 一年で日本語を学ぶことは可能ですか？ means is it possible to learn Japanese in a year.